# Need solution for $f(x)$ in the equation below

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If  $f\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}x-1}{\sqrt{2}x+1}\right)=\log_2(\sqrt{2}x)$, then what is $f(x)$?

I'm rusty with my algebra after not using it for 20+ years. A simple answer to this specific question would be sufficient, though a brief discussion on how to solve such problems in the general case would be even better.

Comment: If you start from defining $t=\frac{\sqrt{2}x-1}{\sqrt{2}x+1}$, you'll have $f(t)$ on the LHS. If you manage to express $x$ as some function $g(t)$, then the RHS will become $\log_2(\sqrt 2g(t))$ and this will be your definition of $f(t)$.

Comment: To even simplify the calculations, note that you have $\sqrt 2 x$ terms everywhere. So I would make the substitution $u=\sqrt 2 x$ first.$$f\left(\frac{u-1}{u+1}\right)=\log_2(u)$$

Comment: Should this read $\sqrt 2 x$ or $\sqrt{2x}$?

Comment: @Lanier Freeman - It's the former.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so we have that

$$f\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}x-1}{\sqrt{2}x+1}\right)=\log_2(\sqrt{2}x).$$

To find a general expression for $f(t)$, simply set

$$t=\frac{\sqrt{2}x-1}{\sqrt{2}x+1}$$

and solve for what $x$ is in terms of $t$. Now multiplying both sides by $\sqrt{2}x+1$ we have that

$$\sqrt{2}xt+t=\sqrt{2}x-1,$$

which we can rearrange to

$$1+t=\sqrt{2}(1-t)x,$$

and finally

$$x=\frac{1+t}{\sqrt{2}(1-t)}.$$

Using this in our original equation we have that

$$f(t)=\log_2\left(\sqrt{2}\cdot\frac{1+t}{\sqrt{2}(1-t)}\right)=\log_2\left(\frac{1+t}{1-t}\right),$$

which is your answer.